# External datasources do not recognize header row of csv exported from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My code follows below

```
HVSPointsJoined = pd.read_csv(r'M:\08_Geography\CurrentSurveys\HVS\HVSMap\pointsjoined.csv',dtype='object')
HVSPointsJoined = HVSPointsJoined[['Join_Count',u'psu', u'tract', u'block',
       u'outcome_code', u'g_short_1', u'lat', u'lon', u'building_type',
       u'description', u'GEOID',u'NTACode']]

typeA_DF = HVSPointsJoined[HVSPointsJoined.outcome_code.isin(['213','214','216','217','218','219'])]
totaltypeA = len(typeA_DF)
ct_typeA = pd.crosstab(typeA_DF.NTACode,typeA_DF.g_short_1)
ct_typeA['Total'] = ct_typeA.sum(axis=1)
ct_typeA[['1','10','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']] = ct_typeA[['1','10','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']].div(ct_typeA['Total'].values,axis=0)
ct_typeA.rename(columns={"1": "TypeA_Per_1",
                    "2": "TypeA_Per_2",
                    "3": "TypeA_Per_3",
                    "4": "TypeA_Per_4",
                    "5": "TypeA_Per_5",
                    "6": "TypeA_Per_6",
                    "7": "TypeA_Per_7",
                    "8": "TypeA_Per_8",
                    "9": "TypeA_Per_9",
                    "10": "TypeA_Per_10"},
               inplace=True)
ct_typeA.drop(['Total'], axis=1)
ct_allCodes = pd.crosstab(HVSPointsJoined['NTACode'],HVSPointsJoined['outcome_code'])
ct_allCodes['Total_Cases'] = ct_allCodes.sum(axis=1)
ct_allCodes['TotalTypeA'] = ct_allCodes['213'] + ct_allCodes['214'] + ct_allCodes['216'] + ct_allCodes['217'] + ct_allCodes['218'] + ct_allCodes['219']
ct_allCodes['PerTypeAofCity'] = ct_allCodes['TotalTypeA']/totaltypeA
ct_allCodes['PerTypeAofNeig'] = ct_allCodes['TotalTypeA']/ct_allCodes['Total_Cases']
ct_buildings = pd.crosstab(HVSPointsJoined['NTACode'],HVSPointsJoined['g_short_1'])

NTATable = pd.concat([ct_allCodes,ct_typeA,ct_buildings],axis=1)
NTATable = NTATable[['200', '201', '202', '203', '204', '205',
                    '213', '214', '216', '217', '218', '219',
                    '226', '229', '230', '232', '233', '240',
                    '243', '244', '245', '247', '248', '305',
                    '321', '401', '580', '583', 'Total_Cases',
                    'TotalTypeA', 'PerTypeAofCity', 'PerTypeAofNeig',
                    'TypeA_Per_1', 'TypeA_Per_2','TypeA_Per_3',
                    'TypeA_Per_4', 'TypeA_Per_5','TypeA_Per_6',
                    'TypeA_Per_7', 'TypeA_Per_8', 'TypeA_Per_9','TypeA_Per_10',
                    'Total', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9','10']]
print(NTATable.head())
print(NTATable.columns.tolist())

NTATable.to_csv(r'M:\08_Geography\CurrentSurveys\HVS\HVSMap\NTA_Tab.csv')
```

The dataframe head prints properly to the screen, as well as the printing of the columns. However, when loading this csv into an external datasource such as excel, excel does not recognize the first row as being a header row. Typically with my other pandas exports the headers are recognized as headers when read into external programs. The first two rows of my csv in notepad look like this

```
    ,200,201,202,203,204,205,213,214,216,217,218,219,226,229,230,232,233,240,243,244,245,247,248,305,321,401,580,583,Total_Cases,TotalTypeA,PerTypeAofCity,PerTypeAofNeig,TypeA_Per_1,TypeA_Per_2,TypeA_Per_3,TypeA_Per_4,TypeA_Per_5,TypeA_Per_6,TypeA_Per_7,TypeA_Per_8,TypeA_Per_9,TypeA_Per_10,Total,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
BK09,2,21,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,40,1,0.000769822940724,0.025,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0,7,0,0,1,14,12,4,2,0
```

I need this csv output to be automated as input for another process so manually assigning the first row in the external program is not an option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Disregard this question, the issue is not related to pandas.  External programs not recognizing a header row if the column names contain numeric characters only.